# Incorrect Display of Plotting

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am graphing a function and I would like to label two points on the axis. One point is labeled correctly, but the other point is displaying the number 4 instead of the corresponding letter. How can I fix this issue?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$f_X(x)$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.6,
    xmax=8,
    samples=100,
    domain=-2:10,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    yticklabels={},
    xticklabel={$\mu$},
    xtick={4},
  ]
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mu}{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{1}
    \addplot[blue, thick] {1/(sqrt(2*pi*\theta^2))*exp(-1/(2*\theta^2)*(x-\mu)^2)};
    \node[below] at (axis cs:\mu, 0) {$\sim$};
    \node[left] at (axis cs:0, {1/(sqrt(2*pi*\theta^2))}) {$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta^2}}$};
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs: \mu,0) -- (axis cs: \mu, {1/(sqrt(2*pi*\theta^2))});
  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this because you defined `\mu` to be `4` using `\pgfmathsetmacro`? (If I am misinterpreting your question, can you edit your question so that the code can be directly copied and compiled, and also include an illustration of the output showing which label is the incorrect one?)

Comment: I updated the code, sorry for that! The \mu defined there is for the value for mu at the function below, is not the same as $\mu$ as I understand.

Comment: No, there is only one defintion of `\mu` and you overwrite this since you are in the same scope. I suggest that you use other names for the variables.